# The visa before German Blue Card

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card

I applied for a blue card at the embassy of Germany in London. I got a visa for 6 months. The lady working there told me this is temporary and that when I arrive to Hamburg I can collect my blue card.

After arriving here, I sent an email to the local foreign office. They replied saying that I need to "apply" for it. And that I need to bring:

- Filled application form
- Passport
- Biometric passport picture
- Rental agreement
- Confirmation of health insurance
- Salary slips you got in Germany until your appointment.

My questions are:

- Does this mean the decision has not been made yet?
- Can an Airbnb booking (for 3-6 months) be considered as a rental
  agreement?
- Can my wife apply for a worker's spouse visa (i.e. family reunion) while
  I am with this temporary working visa? (because the appointement for the blue card is after 2 months)
- Finally, my contract is for one year because I am working on a project. But the company told me they want to keep me after the project. Would a letter showing that the employer intends to employ me permanently extend the period of the blue card at this stage?

Comment: I can't answer your questions authoritatively but I see a different pitfall: did you register with your local Bürgeramt or whatever they call it? Typically there you have to show not the rental agreement but a Wohnungsgeberbestätigung.

Comment: I suspect that the "application" is largely an administrative formality.

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean the decision has not been made yet?

yes, it has not been made yet.

> Can an Airbnb booking (for 3-6 months) be considered as a rental agreement?

It can be, if you signed a proper rental agreement (which probably should be the case, legally). However, I'm not sure if rental agreement for 3-6 month will be enough.

> Can my wife apply for a worker's spouse visa (i.e. family reunion) while I am with this temporary working visa? (because the appointement for the blue card is after 2 months).

AFAIK, you need to get the Blue Card first. Also, you need to have enough living space (in square meters, noted in your rental agreement) to be able to invite your wife, please see http://www.bluecard-eu.de/blaue-karte-eu-deutschland/aufenthaltsgesetz/familiennachzug.html

> Finally, my contract is for one year because I am working on a project. But the company told me they want to keep me after the project. Would a letter showing that the employer intends to employ me permanently extend the period of the blue card at this stage?

Probably not, you will first get the Blue Card for the time of your contract + 3 months, and you need to apply for prolongation of the Blue Card, when your contract will be extended, see point 3.(3) at http://www.bluecard-eu.de/blaue-karte-eu-deutschland/aufenthaltsgesetz/blaue-karte-eu.html