# Changing employer with a Blue Card during Corona crisis, with a lower salary

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a question and I hope some of you may have some advice.
I arrived in Berlin 3 months ago (in February 2020) as a non-EU citizen, and I am a Blue Card holder. I've done the *Anmeldung*, didn't get the chance to attend the appointment for getting a long-term residence permit (valid for 4 years) because of COVID-19 crisis, but I talked to various people and all of them confirmed I have the same rights as other Blue Card holders - I even got a confirmation from LEA that my visa, valid for 6 months, is valid until I don't get the appointment I requested.

Now, I work as an IT engineer, and I am unhappy with my job. Because of this, I found a new job, in the same field, and I signed the contract. Important thing about it is that the salary is a bit lower than at my current job, but it is over the 2020 limit for shortage occupations - but only for shortage occupations. It is lower than the limit required to avoid obtaining a *Zustimmung* from the ZAV, that stills needs to be done. I still meet all the requirements for the Blue Card, because my occupation is on the list of shortage occupations.

Based on this, I did the following: as stated on LEA website, I sent all the documents on their E-Mail address (LEA B1 Berlin branch), and now I have no idea how the process will look like.

Does any of you have any idea what can I expect, and in what time frame?
Will there be any problems because the salary in the new job will be a bit lower than at my current job?
Will my Blue Card only get amended, or a completely new work permit needs to be issued?

Answer (score 1):

Probably my answer arrives too late, but might be still relevant for persons in similar situations. In cases like yours, usually:

1. The Blue Card was not yet issued, so one is not a Blue Card holder (rather he/she is just a visa holder), see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/12606/13223
2. If the salary is below "the limit required to avoid obtaining" agreement from the Job Agency, one will be checked by the Job Agency, see [Blue Card vs Work Permit for IT Specialists](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7074/blue-card-vs-work-permit-for-it-specialists/11514#11514)
3. If one is an IT engineer, he/she can apply not only for Blue Card, but also for other types of residence permit. See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11511/13223 for details.