# Seeking a blue card visa, or getting D-type visa first, and then apply for Blue Card visa for Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, blue-card

My understanding is: I get a D-type/National Visa from the German Embassy in my country, and once I get there in Germany, I will apply for Blue Card.

It was like this until someone told me that one can also apply for Blue Card Visa right from the German Embassy in one's own country, and now I'm confused.

Although I checked with the German Embassy of my country, and on their website, nothing is mentioned related to Blue Card Visa, and all they provide is: National/D-type work visa among other categories, and I couldn't learn anything related to getting Blue Card Visa.

Now, my question is: is there any benefit of getting the Blue Card visa over the National Work visa before entering Germany, as eventually, the National Wok Visa could also lead to a Blue Card in Germany if one qualifies for it.

Comment: it does not really matter, see the related question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12097/13223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is that you apply for a D-Visa at the consulate with all needed documentation

- work contract
- position with salary
- qualifications

etc.

This data will then be sent by the consulate to the local authority in Germany and decided there.

They will make the decision on what **type** of residence permit will be issued after arrival based on the most beneficial type for the applicant.

They will then authorize the consulate to issue the D-Visa, which will contain, in the form of a law paragraph, which type it is.

For a Blue Card: [§ 18b AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0406).

So if the given documentation shows that you qualify for a Blue Card, that is what you will get.

Once you get the D-Visa, just look up the number printed on the visa to see what you got.

Comment: Would like to add one thing here: I'm already applying through section 81a advance approval? I already have the approval from Berlin that I'd take with me when I go to the diplomatic mission.